# Should I try to get my question reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I posted this [Validate number with Decimal Separator and optional Thousands separator with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822997/validate-number-with-decimal-separator-and-optional-thousands-separator-with-reg) question yesterday. Before posting it I tried a bunch of different combinations, and read many posts.

I am not happy to admit, I am not that great with regex, and I don't know anyone that is better than me (I mean in real life). So in the end I posted the question.

Yet I got several downvotes and mark it as duplicate of several questions, none of which have the expression I need and a comment that says:
[image]

Ok so in theory if I keep at it, eventually, I should be able to come with a expression that works (I hope I should at least), and the comment from the closing person basically says I should. I updated my question referencing every question linked as duplicate for mine and gave examples for which the different expressions didn't work.

The closer seems to suggest I should combine them all and make it work. Which btw Is what I was trying to do before posting my question.

So it is wrong from me to ask in this site this kind of question? I thought I covered everything, I stated my issue correctly, I demonstrated I did research, I know that eventually, giving an endless period of time, I should be able to solve it by myself, but I have no way of knowing how long will it take me. But from the comment it seems, if I am theoretically capable of solving the issue, I shouldn't post here.

I know regex is a special case, there are so many, and so many people has posted questions about them. But I went through many, many of those posts, and couldn't find a expression that works correctly for what I feel is a rather extremely common problem, that is why I posted my question.

I would really appreciate your guidance on this. So far I updated my question with comments about the duplicates, and voted to reopen, but I don't know if I should have and if it will actually get reopen.

**Update**

Also, this may seem like a poor excuse, but in general I have great difficulty reading regex because a problem I have with my eyes. So making and spotting small changes on them is hard for me. So I am sorry if the regex I requested is really simple. Maybe someone can suggest me better tools to work with them? For example adding colors actually doesn't help, it makes them harder to read.

Comment: There is a subset of users that don't mind giving you the fish instead of teaching you how to fish.  But it is very, very important to tag the question properly to select them.  Be sure to remove the [javascript] tag.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not sure what you mean, but I put [javascript] because in the past when I asked regex related questions I was requested to point out with with language I was working.

Comment: The problem sounds a bit like an XY problem; "I want to use regex to validate that this input is a valid number." Couldn't you just use an equivalent `IsNumeric`?  Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)?

Comment: @fbueckert do you mean that is why I get the downvotes? Well it is not really my choice, it is code that wasn't done by me and it is using a regex that doesn't work properly, so I am trying to fix that. But I will update my question with that.

Comment: That is important context, I feel.  It may be worth adding that to your question.  Can't you refactor the method to make use of a simpler process?  Regex seems like a super complicated tool for what is essentially numeric validation.

Comment: @fbueckert I updated my question mentioning that. Regarding updating the code, it is a larger javascript structure, and I don't know/understand it all. So I am trying to do the change that has the least potential to break things.

Comment: Remember to include all the limits of your environment (context). Remember, fixing something doesn't mean that you cannot apply other solutions. Explaining what the thing is supposed to do, not only how it's currently broken.

Comment: @Braiam thanks, you are right, I was so caught up with the regex that I could only see the trees and not the forest. Regex actually make me strain my eyes a lot, I rather not use such long ones, hehe. I will take into account for the future what you and fbueckert said.

Comment: @Dzyann you can split the regex into multiple strings/lines which should enable you to see each individual token/statement easier.

Comment: @opa I do that, I split the groups, but still when there are large groups with parenthesis, it is hard for me to follow. I have issues fixing my sight in small parts of text.

Comment: [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/), [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/) and literally dozens of other **identical** sites **exist for a reason**. Coming here for a copy paste solution you will not understand is not useful to you or anyone else and should not be expected from this site. If that is what you want, reddit and other *forums* exists for that kind of expectation.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I dont expect a copy paste solution, but what kind of question  related with regex can you do here then? I cant ask people to explain me how to create the regex I need and I cant ask for the regex. Are you saying we cant ask about regex? Also I would hope anyone posting a solution will help me understand it. I did try to solve the issue, is not like I havent tried. And it is not my choice to use regex, I need to replace an existing one.

Comment: @Dzyann The fundamental issue here is that this is a very basic question, that has been solved, and the solutions published, discussed, dissected, and rediscussed thousands of times over endless easily-accessible resources on the Web. You get the downvotes because *you shouldn't need to ask about this on SO at all*, a simple Google search should get you everything you need, and more.  In general, if you can imagine "many other programmers must have had this same problem before me", that suggests *there is a pre-existing solution easily found via searching*, and you needn't ask on SO.

Comment: @DanBron I understand what you mean. And I dont mind my question being mark as duplicate at all. But when I search for this answer that you say has been solved a gazillion times, all solutions are wrong :S I obviously can't find it, and I have tried a lot, it may be because I am not native english speaker, I even struggled a little finding the correct title. An clear example, the ones that were linked as possible duplicates of my quesiton, I tested all the regex and none work. And I had tried that yesterday and tried modifying them, and couldn't make it work.

Comment: I am sympathetic to that situation. We have all been in it. My suspicion is that you couldn't find what you needed because you had honed in on a solution before you started searching, and then searched for keywords related to that solution. To improve your results, next time, back up, formulate a clear and short *description of the overall problem*, and then search for that ("validating numbers in Java", or whatever).  You may need to search recursively as you come across new terms or concepts in your first search, and dig into those.

Comment: @DanBron I have, I have, I mean many times I even ask friends that speak english to help me rephrase my question. The major issue here is that many people give as valid expresions that actually are not correct, that mark as valid numbers that are wrong, or numbers that are right are signaled as wrong. As I said, I am not great with regex, but I do try, in my original question I even posted an attempt (of many I did), on which I will continue to work on. Even though looking at regex for long periods of time actually give me big headaches because of my messed up eyes.

Comment: @DanBron To sum up, I don't mind the downvotes, I dont mind the duplidate mark. I am actually happy when someone points out a solution right away with minimum effort on their part. The issue is none of those duplicates work, and if you peruse through the many many posts here and in other sites to validate the format I need none work. And it is not a format "I" need, is a format many people request, yet they accept solutions that are totally wrong. Many of the "solutions" accept numbers such as 100.323.123. (Using . as decimal separator, etc)

Comment: Well, I'm convinced that you did your due diligence and honestly are not helped by the duplicates and I have absolutely no problems with the question in its current edited state. I voted to reopen. I get it, the regex tag is one of those special tags much like CSS, HTML and SQL where the tiniest of variations can make answers look like the winner but they're really not.

Comment: @Dzyann Yeah, what I’m trying to point out that focusing on regex is the problem. The problem you have isn’t “what’s a regex for validating numbers”, it’s “validating numbers in java”. Regex is *your proposed solution*, you need to back up a step until you can articulate the actual holistic *problem*, and start your search there. See what I mean? If I’m hungry, and I decide I want a peanut butter and honey sandwich, & I want the honey to be organic clover honey harvested by West Ecuadorian  bumblegrumblers strictly on Tuesdays ... it’s going to be hard. The *problem* is I’m hungry. Start there

Comment: @Gimby thanks, I really appreciate it. I don't really like wasting other people's time. "Don't do unto others what you don't want done unto you." is my motto. But it seems I failed to convey it initially on my question.

Comment: @DanBron Is not my proposed solution, that is the problem, it is the existing solution. That is inside a framework and setup of things that I haven't created and I need to fix. And even then, if you look for validating numbers on javascript that work with regionalization the answer you get many times is to use precisaly, regex. I agree with you, I would rather NOT use regex, I have a system already created with a solution and I have to make it work. Later on maybe I can see if i can do a huge refactor in order not to use the regex, but in the meantime people need to enter the numbers.

Comment: @DanBron as fbueckert pointed out, I failled to mention this initially in my question. Now I have updated it to make it clear.

Comment: @Dzyann Presumably the validation function is exactly that - a function. It has an interface where consumers call and put in strings, and get numbers or errors back out. So long as you maintain that identical interface, the clients *do not care* how the function is actually implemented. Sure, the function body today might have a regex In it. Doesn’t matter to the clients, or to anyone else except you, the coder. You are free to replace the function body / implementation with *any code you see fit*. So the problem comes back to “validating numbers in JS”. No?

Comment: @DanBron no if you just put a string in some place that is used by some other place. I see your point regarding how to solve my issue in general, but it is confusing, because I ask a regex, and the person answer is "dont use regex" when it is even a regex requested many times, just poorly provided. If in SO we don't want to solve regex, maybe we shouldnt allow more questions with that tag? It is really hard for each question to explain why we need a specific thing, it could range from something like "my boss told me so and if I dont do it i get fired" to "i have no clue, what you suggest?"

Comment: @Dzyann It’s not that SO doesn’t want regex Qs. That’s not it at all. I’m not telling you about SO, I’m trying to help you develop a set of skills which will make life easier for you, including using SO. This is “how to think like a graybeard programmer”, not “how to use SO”. The point is to get you to *think* about what the *fundamental problem actually ie*, then start you search on *that topic*. Sometimes yes, absolutely, that will result in a regex Q asked on SO. No problem. But if you’ve done all this thinking and searching first, you will get great answers on SO faster.

Comment: BTW, SO *loves* it, **loves** it, when you give the full background and motivation for why you want a specific thing, why your full constraints are. We wish *all* Qs would include that background. I promise you if you include that information in your future Qs, they’ll get a *much* better reception. (Aside: in order to actually include this information, which SO will reward you for, you necessarily must have done the all the thinking & problem framing I describe above, which will also have the side effect of sharpening the searches you did before SO, so sometimes you don’t have to ask at all!)

Comment: @DanBron what makes you think I haven't done that? In SO we want questions to the point also not extremely verbose, whenever I have explained too much behind my motivations it has backfired. I did forget to mention that I was updating things that were not done by me, but you seem to think that I didn't do any research. The problem started way before, I have a long line of things that happened before, I can't explain them all, some you can't even explain because of privacy reasons.

Comment: @Dzyann I am hearing hurt in your voice, and I had no intention or hurting or insulting you. I’m sorry if I did. I am not here to criticize this specific question, I’m honestly trying to *help you learn how to think about programming problems* in a way that will get you the absolute best use out of SO (and often skip SO altogether). You’re 100% right there’s a balance and it’s also a risk to include too much information. What I’m trying to get across is the hard part is nailing down with *exactly what the problem is*, but if you do that, it’ll be clear exactly how much detail to include.

Comment: But if you still feel my words are hurtful or this conversation is wearing on you, I’m happy to stop commenting, no problem at all. I honestly am trying to help and I’m honestly not trying to criticize.

Comment: @DanBron Bottom line, I asked a question that was useful to many, not only to me, I showed research and defined the issue well. I think downvoting because you think I shouldn't use regex, when you can't posibly know everything that there is to my situation is slightly biased. Even then, people could have asked me "why are you doing this". And I also think is alright, and they are in their right to downvote. But I and I think many people, ask on SO just as last resource. I don't ask unless I am totally stuck and no one I know can help me.

Comment: Also, to be clear, I am not criticizing you for using regex, and I honestly doubt that anyone downvoted you for choosing regex. As I said, I suspect the downvotes are because this is a common problem in regex and has been asked too many times before. The reason I focus on "not regex" is to try to illustrate, using this question only as an example, how to back up to "what the real problem is", which I honestly believe is the principal skill which will solve all your struggles with SO, and even help you skip it most times.

Comment: @DanBron it is alright, but imagine what would you feel if someone tells you "I’m honestly trying to help you learn how to think about programming problems" what makes you think from this situation that you need to teach me that? I am really confused XD If you said "I am trying to help you see the problem from another perspective", but you think I am looking at my problem wrong when you don't know everything there is to my problem and I can't possibly explain you, although I have tried to explain you that is not my decision right now to use the regex.

Comment: @Dzyann From this particular situation, what made me think that is that many people — there is a pattern — jump to the conclusion “regex” too quickly. In this particular case, I still can see no reason why you can’t replace `bool validateNumber(string userInput) { userInput ~~ /some regex/ }` with `bool validateNumber(string userInput) { Decimal.isValid(userInput); }` etc. I have seen many people focus too tightly on the “some regex” and not broadly enough on “validateNumber”. I’m extrapolating, but nothing currently in your Q tells me I’m extrapolating incorrectly for you. That’s all.

Comment: Here is the most famous example of this constantly recurring “substitute solution for problem” pattern on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/2562182. The answer is so popular because the mistake for OPs is so very very common.

Comment: @DanBron I get your point, and is alright I suppose, but I think is a bit against the spirit of SO? I did ask a question clearly, it is useful for many people besides me and I showed research. And it is not "some regex" it is a regex I am amazed hasnt been done properly in any place, it has to be, but I can't find it. It is not some crazy capricious validation, it is a rather standard request, I shouldn't need to make it, yet many people has requested, and many answers exists, all of them wrong. Which makes my question even more valid. We need the correct regex somewhere.

Comment: @DanBron And just to clarify, if it was up to me I break half the application in order to solve this in a nicer way. But it is what It is, I am trying to solve the issue in the least breaking way. Am I satisfied with the regex? NO. Is the regex guaranteed not to break other things? NO, but it looks like is the least breaking thing. To compare my question to that one you posted, where you can obviously see the problem goes beyond a regex, and I know you dont use regex to match open/closing elements. I asked for a regex in the regex tag, because I decided it was the best path to go.

Comment: `I think downvoting because you think I shouldn't use regex, when you can't posibly know everything that there is to my situation is slightly biased` - This is literally why the downvote button exists.  Regex is likely the wrong solution to this problem, so, yes, people *should* downvote if they believe the question is not useful.  It's more an overcomplication of the problem space.  Subscribe to the KISS principle.

Comment: @Dzyann “The correct regex” can’t exist because you specifically say you need to handle regionalization. Regexes by their very definition are context-free, and so at very least there would need to be pre-processing of the input, post-processing of the output, or programmatic & contextual construction of the regex at runtime. But all that is immaterial. This is a divergence from what we were discussing. I was not discussing “what’s best for the world”, I was trying to help *you* solve problems better & as a side effect use SO more effectively. Plus the dupe says your Q *didn’t* help the world.

Comment: @fbueckert But, regex are to match patterns, you don't know why I need to match this particular pattern, why do you think I shouldn't use regex? I understand when I gave no additional information, but when I tell you have to use it because it is how it was done in the previous system? And also It could be just out of curiosity. There is proof that the requested regex is useful because many people has asked for it (without downvotes) but the solutions I could find so far were wrong.

Comment: @DanBron so the "duplication mark" Actually helps a lot. That is why I never take offense by them. You can see my user, you will see I have asked other questions that were marked as duplicate. People thoughts are hard to index, because different people think and talk different, so a duplicate, I think, is really useful, a better or differently phrased question can help more people find the solution. But in this case, the duplicates are not even correct, since they dont cover the problem.

Comment: @Dzyann I think we’re talking in circles. You are insisting that the question is valid because you decided on the proposed solution and wanted to ask about that solution, and I’ve been saying since the beginning that that is why you’re struggling with SO, which is *what you are asking about in this Meta-Q*. This whole conversation has been me trying to point you to a better way. We don’t need to discuss that any more. Or at least I don’t. As for “proof”: the fact that your question was closed as a dupe and you agree the dupe asked the same Q says *your Q was not needed*.

Comment: And yet, your question is still downvoted.  We're trying to build a *lasting* knowledgebase of information.  How useful is a question that crams the wrong attempted solution in the grand scheme of things?  Regex can be *a* solution, but here, I think, it's not the solution you should be using.  It's much more useful for future readers to read, "Don't use regex for this problem.  Use this much more simple method that does not have the problems regex does."

Comment: @fbueckert if that is the case I think we need to close and downvote all the other questions that ask the same thing but have the wrong answer and yet a bunch of upvotes? This compares to, my car is broken, buy a new one or fix it? It would be nicer to buy a new one, sometimes, you have to fix it. But that is why I asked here, because despite the evidence given by the upvotes to other similar questions mine was ill-received. So far, It is clear that is better not to ask about regex here and go to other sites as suggested by other users. (which is a valid outcome for my question)

Comment: @Dzyann I don’t know any other way to put this, since I’ve said it so many time as already: the problem is not asking about regexes on SO.

Comment: It takes far more effort to glean the correct answer than to just answer the surface question; SO isn't immune to that.  Curators that take the longer view are much rarer than those just looking for a simple answer.  Should they be downvoted?  Probably.  But more users find spoonfed answers more useful than more general answers that require more work from them.  That's human nature.  But those more general answers are more useful across a wider audience, and that's why they're better.  Solve the root problem, not the problem you think you have.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree with that. And that is why I asked, sometimes you need to fix the car, sometimes you can buy a new one. I can't change everything in my app. God knows I would change so many things, coworkers have to stop me sometimes. If these questions are not welcomed here, I won't make them anymore. But from the available evidence it seemed like it was welcomed. You can't know unless you ask. And it also bothered me that the "acepted regexs" were all wrong. It would be nice to have at least once that regex properly written in some place.

Comment: The thing about regexes is that there generally *isn't* a canonical that fits every situation.  They're region agnostic, so making them fit perfectly the world over, for every region, is going to be a massive struggle, as you're noticing.  Yes, sometimes you have to fix the car, and that's why we allow these questions, but in terms of utility, they're not nearly as useful as solving the root problem.  As with fixing cars, solving the root problem takes more effort *now*, but saves you so much time going forward, so is almost always better than patching the problem and poking it in the future.

Comment: @fbueckert It is true that there isn't a canonical solution that fits every situation because of the region issues. I am taking smalls steps to solve the core issue, the first part is that we are fixing everything to one region, but the regex has to work properly at least on that one region, and none of the ones you find on internet seem to do so. Then we have to review how to remove the regex completely. But right now we are at the point where user can't even input values.

Comment: @fbueckert my major issue is politcal, can't very well add that detail to a question, so I am just left with asking about the regex. I think everyone that has worked on IT, or anything really, has come across the politcal considerations to solving problems. That is where I am at. And the regex for now is the only possible solution. But as Jarrod, I think, said, I can ask in other forums.

Comment: I still think you're burning so much extra time for no good reason.  This is a solved problem.  Part of being a programmer is pointing out that there's a better way.  If the bosses reject it, that's one thing.  Discarding it, "because that's the way it is" does you, and your company, a disservice.

Comment: @fbueckert when I say "that is the way it is" I am refering to the situation where I have talked with people, not that I haven't tried. We are taking baby steps, first make it work, then make it pretty, and we have a technical debt stack too, where we can add this items.

Comment: as you have been told over and over the the correct solution is to just try and parse the number with javascript function, that is the **idiotmatic** way to do number validation in JavaScript. This [**is a solved problem**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric) the fact that you insist on wanting to do it in regex is irrelevant, the root question is *validate numbers in javascript*, that is the question that is useful to everyone else, you insistence that regex is the question that is useful to everyone else is **false**.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I think NOW, I understand where the misunderstanding is coming from. I put the "javascript" tag, just to point out the regex syntax, is not a problem I can solve using the idiomatic Javascript way, "IsNumeric" fails in this context. I removed javascript tag so It doesn't lead to more confusion.

Comment: removing the JavaScript tag does not make it the correct answer to the **root cause question**. Regardless of **language** the correct answer is *use whatever native function your language has for parsing numbers*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson but my question is how to build the regex, because when I tried to build a regex to match what I need I had issues. The question you are imagining is something else. The root cause question is not even what you are saying, because if I were to use IsNumeric, it wouldn't work. My issue at grand has to do with conflicting technologies and regions. In the place where is failing (which I didn't implement) it does because a bad regex.

Comment: that is exactly why it is an `X/Y Problem` as you have been told over and over as well. You are asking a question about a solution (which is not the solution), instead of the problem.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I am not sure what to do anymore. I want to know how to build that regex, THAT is my question, everything else, doesn't matter, even, even if I was never going to use this regex, I want to know how to build it. WHich is the main reason I asked this question. Barmar has helped me, now I understand regex a bit more. I used poor phrasing stating my question, and I have been trying to clarify, I just want to know how to build this regex and you keep telling me I want to use IsNumeric. I want to know how to build the regex. That is why I even asked an explanation on Barmans Answer

Comment: A question is only a duplicate if all possible answers to the current question are also possible answers to the target question, and vice versa. A question cannot be a duplicate of multiple questions combined, as googlers who aren't signed in will be automatically redirected to only one of those questions, and they won't get their answer. It could be too broad though if it is actually trying to solve multiple unrelated problems at the same time, instead of one problem (or multiple directly linked/dependent problems), or unclear if it is not well-defined (ambiguous or open to interpretation)

Comment: If you asked the actual question *How to parse/convert Strings to Numbers regardless of the locale format of the String?*, you would not get this *regex* as the answer. Like I said, you have been told that this is the **actual problem**, but you insist that your **solution** is the *problem*, and it isn't. It is *How to parse/convert Strings to Numbers regardless of the locale format of the String*, if that question got a *regex* as an answer, that *"answer"* would be down voted into oblivion because it would be **incorrect**, especially for beginners finding it in the future.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson what I want to know is how to write that regex. How would you ask that? I dont care about parsing, or anything, I want to know how to write that regex (well I already know because Barmar wrote it) I think I added a lot of information that muddle the question. I just want to know how to write the regex, because I tried to write it and when I tried to match certain patterns it didn't work, and each change I did also failed.

Comment: @Dzyann I think one must take Hans' comment as tongue-in-cheek. If your question is a javascript one, it should of course be tagged javascript. However, the tongue-in-cheek part is Hans suggesting that if you are following proper site conventions by tagging a JS question with JS, then you should also follow other site conventions that he is implying are proper, which includes asking for a fish rather than for help with learning how to fish. This implication, however, is not actually a site policy; it is perfectly acceptable site behavior to answer the question asked rather than teach broadly.

Comment: @TylerH Ohh, I had no idea what he meant. Yeah I got bitten by tagging my question as Javascript, I just was referring to the format, I wanted to know how to build a Regex and I managed to confuse everyone and get them mad at me.

Comment: @Dzyann For a regex, we usually need to know the language because there are different regex "flavours" in different languages.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I know, but putting javascript and poor phrasing from my part lead people to believe my issue was other than "I want to write this regex." And then I tried to explain it, and somehow I dug a bigger hole XD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you got the short end of the stick on this one.

The big thing here is that a lot of these votes aren't telling you that your question is *bad* or somehow otherwise poor quality.  These votes appear to indicate that they don't *like* what you're asking about, or they don't like your solution.

Now it's fine for people to not like your question or your approach, but I would also expect to see some **answers on your question** in reference to what a more preferable approach would be as opposed to raking you over the coals (in comments no less) behind *why* your approach is wrong.

No one comes to Stack Overflow to hear why they are doing it wrong, and instead of being given an opportunity to hear a different answer, you were just...treated poorly for that.

Sorry about that.

It's fine to ask this kind of question here, but you do have to be prepared to accept a *different* kind of answer to the one you were looking for.  There are a few different ways to solve problems like this, and it's important to keep that in mind when going through this exercise.

Comment: "The big thing here is that a lot of these votes aren't telling you that your question is bad or somehow otherwise poor quality." But they *are*.  They're saying that the question was poorly asked, and is not useful as a result, and also that it's extremely poorly researched.  No one is saying they just don't like it.

Comment: @Servy:  You're going to have to ***explain*** this one to me.  I see a question which has the kind of data the OP is trying to compare against, what they've tried, where they've *failed*, and what prior research they've attempted.  By the book, **this question is _fine_**.  What's not fine is that it's using Regex as a way to solve this problem - and while I probably wouldn't either, that's not really a reason to downvote the question.  What are *you* seeing?   I genuinely want to know since I don't want to be missing something important here.

Comment: Given that there's already like 75 comments on this meta question already explaining the problems with this question, I don't really see a need to repeat any of what's been said any more than it's already been said.

Comment: Funnily enough I based most of my belief that this was a question that wasn't liked on the comment exchange.  A snippet of the exchange exists in the question itself as a picture but remains unlinked/hidden for when the comments are deleted.  I cannot see anything there other than "XY problem"-this and "don't use Regex"-that in the comments, which would ***beg*** for an answer which doesn't use ***any*** of that.  The fact that there's a **40+ comment chain** arguing over the question as it's stated tells me that the commentators really *don't* want to answer it.

Comment: Yes, commentors pointing out problems with the question is indeed them indicating that they don't want to answer it.  We don't want to answer questions that aren't useful.  That's...kinda the premise of the site.

Comment: ...and it's fine to not want to answer the question.  But that doesn't make the question objectively bad.  I saw ***nothing*** in the question to make me believe that it deserved *any* kind of negative voting.

Comment: So let me get this straight.  You don't want to answer a question which asks how to validate that a number comes in in the correct decimal and comma-delimited format, and you also don't think that such a question is not useful?

Comment: And yet you said yourself that you don't think it's a useful question, because you don't think it's a good idea to be trying to use a regex to parse a number.  Given that questions that a reader thinks aren't useful should be downvoted, *you* think the question should be downvoted.

Comment: Asking how to parse a number is not an original question here.  There are already posts that tell you how to parse a number.  Thus, indeed, it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: @Servy:  Where'd I say that specifically?  I merely stated that I wouldn't respond with a regex solution.  That doesn't mean that the question isn't useful.

Comment: The question specifically says that it *needs* to be a regex, so such an answer wouldn't answer the question as asked.  Also, again, *this is not the first question asking how to parse a number*, so that wouldn't merit an answer if that was what the question were actually asking.

Comment: I agree @Makoto, this is not a good way to treat a user.  Sure, it's good in a larger perspective to point out that there are better ways to solve a problem, I often leave answers/comments like that myself.  A young developer can be shy about really re-writing a section of code, rather than just trying to fix the regex. But the kind of vituperation that Dzyann is being subjected to, because mostly one person thinks regex is horrible, is really beyond the pale.  If it takes 23 comments to express your indignation, you can pretty much conclude that it's excessive..

Comment: @Servy:  So then it'd be best suited to be closed as a dupe.  If you've got one lined up, then go ahead and link to it.  No commentation is required in that regard; no back-and-forth; just a "hey, here's a solution for you over yonder".  No need for anything else, really.

Comment: @Makoto The question *was* closed as a duplicate.  The whole meta question is here because the OP didn't like that.  And now you've posted an answer apologizing on behalf of the community for closing the question as a duplicate, despite the fact that you think that's the appropriate course of action.

Comment: @Servy:  That tells me that the dupe was insufficient or inappropriate.  The only one I can see in the post history would be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric) but that's not a complete answer either, since it only indicates how to check if a single number is numeric, not formatted in a specific way.  Maybe trincot could elaborate on what they closed it as and we could go from there.

Comment: @Servy:  The whole *point* of closing as a dupe is to be sure that the OP gets an answer.  If they don't feel like they got an answer from the dupe, they are empowered to edit their question and illustrate why it's not an answer.  I'm not sure why you're getting worked up over the fact that someone is using the system as prescribed.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not concerned that they indicated they didn't feel the duplicate answered their question.  I'm concerned that you think that "how do I parse a numeric string" is a novel and high quality javascript question that doesn't deserve downvotes, or close votes (or that that's the question that was actually asked, even if that's the problem the OP actually needs to solve).

Comment: @Servy:  My biggest issue is with the how the OP was treated in the comment chain on this Meta question.  I maintain that if the OP doesn't feel like their question was sufficiently answered they can edit and try again, **and the system allows for that**.  I never said anything about it being novel or high-quality, just that I don't see anything that immediately justifies downvotes.  The impression I got from the comment chain above was that it was just not liked.

Comment: @Servy:  Only way we're going to stop seeing campaigns about how Stack Overflow isn't welcoming is if we start identifying circumstances in which this occurs.  **Here's one right in front of us.** The way the OP was treated wasn't very good.  I maintain - if it was a sufficient dupe then all that needed to be done was explain *why* it was a good dupe, and if it wasn't a good dupe, then the community has done its job in reopening the question in the service of getting them an answer.

Comment: Hi Makoto, I had I made a mistake in the way I phrased the question and this led people to believe that I wanted to solve a problem and they thought using regex was the wrong call. Now I do have a problem and I don't want to solve it with regex. However while I am working on that problem I came across the need of said Regex, and I found I was not capable of writing it, so I opened a question. And then got myself tangled in this argument. From SO I wanted to write that Regex and I got it thorugh Barmar that kindly explained my error.

Comment: Hi @Dzyann - I'm a little confused at your explanation.  You discovered that writing the regex was a poor choice for one of your problems, but you needed to use regex for another problem?

Comment: Also one finally update. To truly solve the underlaying issue that brought me to work on this regex I expect I shouldn't write any javascript, so the IsNumeric that some people suggest wouldn't be needed (not that I do know how to find Jquery.IsNumeric, for instance), my actual question was that I wanted to know how to build the regex. But I failed miserably at stating it.

Comment: Lol, no you see I keep confusing people don't even know how. The initial problem is rather complex and can't be asked on SO. While working on it, I came accross a momentary need for a Regex. Now a poor regex would have been enough. But I wanted (As a challenge I guess) to write a regex that matched exactly the format I wanted. That is what I wanted, I tried and researched a lot and failed at it. So I asked here the question, but did some poor choices and led people to believe I was having issues with Javascript, etc. When I just wanted to know how to write that regex.

Comment: Okay then @Dzyann, that does sound like the classic XY problem then.  Kind of wish you got less verbose feedback for that kind of thing as opposed to...this...

Comment: @Makoto And if you continue to campaign that questions like, "how do I parse a numeric string in javascript" are well research high quality questions that shouldn't be downvoted, closed as a duplicate, nor should anyone ever comment on them to indicate that they're in any way problematic, then you're going to drive away all of the quality minded users and you no longer get useful answers to questions.  Being "welcoming" doesn't mean, "Removing all semblance of quality standards and claiming all questions are good questions, and anyone providing any negative feedback is a bad person."

Comment: @Servy:  You have failed to illustrate how I'm advocating for a reduction in quality here.  I think we're going to have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: @Servy I didnt actually ask that, that is the problem, and I don't mind if my questions are closed as duplicate, you can see I have questions closed as duplicate that I never said a thing. The long discussion has been me trying to explain what I really wanted, and people telling me that is wrong because I want something else. I never said that the correct way to parse numbers in javascript is a regex, nor I would do that. I don't like to reinvent the wheel. I tried to write a regex for a generic pattern that somehow I couldn't find and asked help. I am sorry I wrote it in a confusing way.

Comment: @Makoto People pointed out problems with the quality of the question, and you responded by saying that that's what's making SO unwelcoming, and that people downvoting or closing a question is "not treating the author very good".  When you define downvoting a question that you think isn't useful as not treating the author well, that's you saying you're advocating for a reduction in quality.

Comment: @Dzyann Well Makoto was saying that all your question was asking is how to parse a numeric string in javascript, I was responding to that.  I have indicated in several comments that I don't feel that's what your question is asking.  One of the main problems with your question is that it doesn't actually do a good job of explaining the *actual* problem, hence why everyone is telling you that your question is an XY question.  Explaining the actual problem you're trying to solve would help address that.

Comment: @Servy Well the thing is that I have been trying to clarify that what I want to know is how to write the regex and that was the question, which got answered. I didn't know how to write that regex. Which I think is a legitimate question too, I just phrased it poorly.

Comment: I gotta agree with @Servy here, Makoto.  This has all the markings of an XY problem, and defending it as good is...kind of astonishing, I feel.  It's a very contrived problem, with no real backing as to why it has to be a regex, other than the continued insistence that it must be.  That doesn't sound like a quality question to me in any sense; it sounds like a super specific, localized issue that nobody else will encounter, because its jumps straight to a supposed solution, instead of explaining the problem.  How is this question going to be useful to readers in the future?

Comment: @Makoto - on the 'welcoming' thing, you seem to be putting all the blame on the established user(s) for causing a long, drawn-out discussion, which (I agree) doesn't represent a great example of the SO community, but you can't deny that it takes two to draw out a discussion. Dzyann also chose to continually ignore the (good) advice being given and repeat the same argument without explaining the background to the problem.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I didn't ignore the advise, you can't give background to everything, there are privacy reasons, etc. What I don't get is this, if I want to know how to write a regex? Why can't I ask? Everyone wrongly asumed that the original problem ought to be solved with Javascript. The reason we need a regex is that there is a problem that goes well beyond Javascript, and If I can solve it, it wont be with Javascript. In any case I wasn't asking about that problem, I can't. In this particular case I just wanted to know how to write that regex, because I tried, and I failed.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I didn't come here thinking "solve my problem". I came here thinking "could you help me write this regex properly and tell me where I am failing?" I gave details I shouldn't have in the question, I tried to explain it later, but I couldn't make people understand me. That is why I asked here too, is it wrong to ask what I asked? I mean about regex, not what people thought I asked, is it wrong to ask "how do you write this regex?". I can accept if the comunity thing it is wrong, and I can go to another site to get that kind of help.

Comment: No, as many have already said, it's not wrong. But unfortunately the answer to "how do I write a regex to perfectly validate decimal numbers" is "you can't". People have told you this several times. You could easily have edited your question to add something like "The reason I need to use regex is top-secret and I can't possibly tell you, but I do have to use regex". It wouldn't have changed the answer, but would have cut short the discussion, which is what Makoto was objecting to. Addressing that was in your power, just as much as the more established users.

Comment: Your reluctance to add background information explaining _why_ it has to be regex, though, appears as a red flag that you might not have thought about other options - I can't imagine any realistic scenario where you're in a secret world with a language that supports regex but doesn't have any other options for validating numbers - it's possible, of course, but just seems _off_. Generally speaking, these questions come about because the asker has missed some trivial feature of their language. Without knowing any background it's natural that people will assume the same here.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave ok, I get your point. But do you get my point that maybe I just want to know how to write that regex? Beyond the actual problem, I want to know how to write the regex, and it is why I asked in SO at all? And you can write the regex because I got an answer that works perfectly. I just was trying to match a pattern and I coulnd't write it and I searched all over the place and existing patterns were working wrong. My resistances to explain anything is because I just want to know how to write it and I don't get why people can't understand that sometimes you just want to know.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I did give some more background in this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185445/discussion-between-dzyann-and-jarrod-roberson that didn't help. The reality is I want to know how to write the regex, that was my sole motivation when I wrote the question, I gave stupid detail I shouldn't have because lead people to believe I was having some javascript issue they could help me with, I am not. The issue is not Javascript. From what I gather so far is that the client wants the site to work in a way it shouldn't so basically you are stuck with writing a regex.

Comment: I do get your point, and it's reasonable, but not really what SO aims to be. It intends to be a repository of knowledge that can help many people, not just one person who wants to understand something for academic curiosity. When someone searches for "how do I validate a number with regex" the absolute best advice 99.999% of the time for them will be "don't, there's a better way". This is why the tooltip on 'downvote' says "This answer is not useful". The answer you have will only work in a limited number of localities, I'm not sure about other issues that it may or may not have.

Comment: @Dzyann:  Remember, I did say that you needed to be prepared to accept a *different* solution to your problem.  Regex isn't the end-all be-all of everything.

Comment: @Makoto yes I know, I mean if people would have told me not to reopen the question I would have said "ok" when I ask, I am truly asking, It is not rethorical. I just have seen several questions in the regex tag, so I thought it was ok to ask about how to write a regex, I just shouldn't have added further detail that confused everyone. (Although In my defense I have seen similarly phrased questions that got no issue, of course that doesn't mean those questions are ok)

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I can see that is valid. But the reason I asked is that I saw a bunch of similar question, all of them with the wrong regex. Now You could say I was aiming to have a question about that regex with an answer that actually worked. Because right now there is a bunch of answers that just don't work, I guess they were poorly tested? I also get I should be more specific so people don't misunderstand me. And if in the future I have issues with regex like this I will ask in one of the sites that Jarrod mentioned to avoid more trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was really not a bad question. There are 6 upvotes and 10 downvotes, meaning that at least *some* users thought it was a good question. The downvotes may have come from things other than quality.

As for reopening, you did the best thing to do in that situation: editing and voting to reopen. If you don't think your post is a duplicate, always edit to explain why and vote to reopen if you have 250+ reputation. It will get reopened if enough users agree that it's not a duplicate.

Comment: six upvotes is generally (not always) an indication that is a very good question. In this case, though, I'm thinking much of those votes were from the Meta effect.